# What kind of connection is the directional derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Given a scalar function $f(X)$ as a function of coordinates I can write it's directional derivative in direction $\hat{u}$ as:

$$ D_{\hat{u} } f = \nabla f \cdot \hat{u}$$

This is pretty easy to think about and understand. I recently learned about the concept of connections which is supposed to 'abstract' the idea of directional derivatives from $(0,0)$ tensor fields (scalar fields to a general $(p,q)$ tensor field. Here's the definition I learned:

> A connection $\nabla$ on a smooth manifold $(M,\theta,A)$ is a map that takes a pair consisting of a vector field and a $(p,q)$ tensor field $T $and sends that to a $(p,q)$ tensor field $\nabla_x T$ From [20:15](https://youtu.be/nEaiZBbCVtI?t=1215)

From what I understand, there are actually many possible connections which we could define but the Levi civita connection with the torsion free and metric compatibility is the often used.

In the abstract case , I learned we have to put more constraints to specify how to take a connection then this would mean we would have taken those same assumption in taking the directional derivatives. My question is what is the connection we take to get the directioncal derivative? [Eg: Is it levi civita, or boring connection or something else?]

[I got that the connection is determined by the further constraints in at [16:35](https://youtu.be/cEEahoUUGyc?t=995) ]

Comment: Are you asking what is the definition of a connection?

Comment: No, not at all, what made you think that? @ArticChar

Comment: Sorry, I think then I completely don't understand your last paragraph.

Comment: Are you looking for something like, "The directional derivative is the Levi-Civita connection of the Euclidean metric"?

Comment: The course I am doing hasn't introduced metric spaces yet but sounds like what I want @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: The definition of the directional derivative of a function requires no connection or any other geometric structure on the manifold. You don't even need the dot product. The proper definition is the following: Given a point $p$ and a tangent vector $v$, there is a smooth curve $c$ such that $c(0) = p$ and $c'(0) = v$. The directional derivative of a function $f$ at $p$ in the direction $v$ is defined to be $$D_vf(p) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(c(t)).$$ You can verify that this is independent of the curve and coordinates used to calculate it.

Comment: Oh , that is insightful :) @Deane

Comment: If you want to define the directional derivative of a vector or tensor field in a similar way, then there is no natural definition without introducing something new. The concept of a connection is exactly what's needed.

Comment: If I understood correct, no matter what connection you take, all of them coincide with the directioncal derivative of scalar field? @Deane

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Because the connection isn't even used in the calculation of the directional derivative of a scalar field.

Comment: If you could add in an explanation why we need more structure for defining directioncal derivative of tensor fields with the comment you have put right now, I'll gladly accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$ The directional derivative of a function is well-defined on a manifold without any additional assumptions. In particular, given a smooth function $f: M \rightarrow \R$, $p \in M$, and tangent vector $v \in T_pM$, we can define the directional derivative to be
$$ D_vf(p)= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(c(t)) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(c(t))-f(c(0))}{t},$$
where $c$ is a smooth parameterized curve such that $c(0) = p$ and $c'(0) = v$.
It is straightforward, using local coordinates and the chain rule, to show that this is well-defined, independent of the curve $c$ and the local coordinates.

If we tryto define the directional derivative of a vector field $X$ the same way, we get something like
$$ D_vX(p)= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}X(c(t)) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{X(c(t))-X(c(0))}{t}.$$
This, however, doesn't work, because $X(c(t)) \in T_{c(t)}M$ and $X(c(0)) \in T_{c(0)}M$ lie in different vector spaces, so it is not possible to subtract one from the other. You have to "transport" one of them to be in the same tangent space as the other. The process of doing this is a long story. In short, there is not a unique way to do it, and involves setting up a so-called connection on the tangent bundle of the manifold.